# JQM Padding With Hidden Elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Sample fiddle of my problem:
**http://fiddle.jshell.net/FS8rj/**

I have a few places where I don't want users to be able to delete something out of a  collapsible using an icon -- so I want to hide this icon completely.

It seems jQuery Mobile puts padding for each element in the collapsible so that elements don't clump together.

I tried refreshing the entire list-view, but jQuery Mobile doesn't recognize that I've hidden an element with jQuery and it continues to add the padding regardless.  I know one workaround is to disable the icon rather than hide it, but I don't want to leave it greyed out on the screen at all.

Is it possible to disable this without overwriting it with more css or similar methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile adds `ui-li-has-alt` to `li` with split button. All you need is to remove that class and add it back when you show the button again.

> [**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Hetkg/)

```
$('li').removeClass('ui-li-has-alt');
```

**Edit:** Using `.closest()` to remove class from parent `li`.

```
$('.hide').hide().closest('li').removeClass('ui-li-has-alt');
```

Comment: Oh, neat.  Thanks @Omar. The only thing I changed here was your jQuery selector to be $('.delete').parent().removeClass('ui-li-has-alt');

If I were to use your selector, then every li on the page would be affected -- even ones that I hadn't marked with .delete in my example.  This way, you could intertwine elements you would want to have the icon and not.  For example this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hJyzq/

Comment: @EricHotinger or use `.closest()` which you will often use it in JQM `$('.hide').hide().closest('li').removeClass('ui-li-has-alt');` http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/hJyzq/1/

Answer (score 2):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/njAt4/

Just wrap the a tag in a div with your delete class, and then it works as you wish.

```
<div class="delete">
   <a href="#" data-rel="popup" data-mini="false" data-position-to="window" data-icon="delete"></a>
</div>
```

This will remove the delete icon on this node entirely.

Comment: jQuery mobile seems to leave the styles of things alone if you do this.  I stumbled onto this when trying to have a custom header and the documentation mentioned:

"If you need to create a header that doesn't follow the default configuration, simply wrap your custom styled markup in any container, such as div. The plugin won't apply the automatic button logic to the wrapped content inside the header container so you can write custom styles for laying out the content in your header."

Comment: On second thought, this will remove the icon regardless if the class is there or not, and may not be what you're looking for!

Comment: Yep. This is actually not what I want.  I want to be able to select any given class and remove all the icons from them. 

+1 for noticing this though.  Very bizarre as well...

Answer (score 1):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/YGCQM/

The solution was to override the right css attribute of the "ui-li-count" to 10px.  It gets changed to 53px when there is a button, hidden or not.

```
if (reportViewModel.hasDisabledExpenses()) {
    $('.delete').hide();
    $('.delete').parent().find(".ui-li-count").css("right", "10px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander.  I gave Omar the accepted answer because it explicitly references the class that causes the issue.